# Use jar file resource while running from intellij idea IDE

Tags: java, jar

I have a java project that uses a resource file that is put into the jar file. All runs well while starting it with java -jar app.jar. But running it from a IDE, it doesn't find the file.

Is it possible to run and debug the project from the IDE?

Comment: Can you please describe in detail *how* it doesn't work? And some code would be nice, too.

Answer (score 4):

Just in case anyone is still looking I solved this by creating the jar as an artefact.

To get the resources I use -jar path/to/my.jar in VM options in Edit configurations in the Run menu.

Answer (score 1):

Goto "open module setting" by right clicking the project. add the jar as a library in project setting. go to dependency tab of the module and add that.

Comment: There is no jar file yet. I build a jar file from a project and a file is put in that container. The file is accessable by getClass().getResourceAsStream(file). But only if the Project is running with java -jar app.jar. When I start it direct from the IDE, it will not find the file.